# python pandas count repeat items in consecutive transactions

Tags: python, pandas, count, distinct

Working with this dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | transaction_nr | item_ID
ABC            1                6438097
ABC            2                9703489
ABC            2                6438097
BCD            1                0093753
BCD            2                9084378
BCD            3                9084378
```

I want to calculate the distinct count of Customer_IDs that have the same item_ID in transaction 1 & 2. Seperately, I want to calculate the distinct count of Customer_iDs that have the same item_if in transaction 2&3.

How can I go about it, without manually pivoting and counting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a groupby apply:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "item_ID"]).apply(lambda x: x["transaction_nr"].isin([1, 2]).sum() == 2)
Out[11]:
Customer_ID  item_ID
ABC          6438097     True
             9703489    False
BCD          93753      False
             9084378    False
dtype: bool

In [12]: df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "item_ID"]).apply(lambda x: x["transaction_nr"].isin([2, 3]).sum() == 2)
Out[12]:
Customer_ID  item_ID
ABC          6438097    False
             9703489    False
BCD          93753      False
             9084378     True
dtype: bool

# To get the count:
In [13]: df.groupby(["Customer_ID", "item_ID"]).apply(lambda x: x["transaction_nr"].isin([2, 3]).sum() == 2).sum()
Out[12]: 1
```

Here, the apply:

```
.apply(lambda x: x["transaction_nr"].isin([1, 2]).sum() == 2)
```

checks whether there is both transaction_nr 1 and 2 (if there is the sum will be 2), also for 2 and 3.

*Note: you may have to `.drop_duplicates` first, depending if that's guaranteed in your dataset.*

Comment: I received it too, :-) hope they can give the reason

Answer (score 1):

Just call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and pass [`pd.Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts):

```
In [212]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)

Out[212]:
   a  b  c  d
0  4  6  4  3
1  6  4  6  7
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['Customer_ID'],df['transaction_nr'],df['item_ID'],aggfunc=len)
    Out[795]: 
    transaction_nr    1    2    3
    Customer_ID                  
    ABC             1.0  2.0  NaN
    BCD             1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Here is the check the id

```
pd.crosstab(df['Customer_ID'],df['item_ID'],df['transaction_nr'].isin([1,2]),aggfunc=sum)
Out[798]: 
item_ID      93753    6438097  9084378  9703489
Customer_ID                                    
ABC              NaN      2.0      NaN      1.0
BCD              1.0      NaN      1.0      NaN
```

Comment: thank you so much, I upvoted the answer and am testing it now